# why I cannot remove the original werkzeug handler?

Tags: python, logging, flask

I am running a flask server on my machine and I want to add the existing werkzeug log to my own handler, I tried to use the following code:

```
myhandler = ...

flask_logger = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
for hdl in flask_logger.handlers:
    flask_logger.removeHandler(hdl)

flask_logger.propagate = False
flask_logger.addHandler(handler)
```

but when I run the flask server, I saw two logs for each request I make, one is from my own handler, the other I think from the original werkzeug handler, why they are not removed?